# A custom attribute is specified with missing attributes code in magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2.3.1

I am facing a problem when i add customer field in checkout page, Magento 2.3.1 I am receiving this error when A custom attribute is specified without attribute code.

Comment: Please provide the code which you have used. From your content, we do not understand  from this content

Comment: sir my requirement is i want to add zone number and street number field in magento 2.3.1 checkout page.can you help me